# Practical algorithms for permuting external memory

Tags: algorithm, permutation, large-data, large-files

On a spinning disk, I have N records that I want to permute. In RAM, I have an array of N indices that contain the desired permutation. I also have enough RAM to hold n records at a time. What algorithm can I use to execute the permutation on disk as quickly as possible, taking into account the fact that sequential disk access is a lot faster?

I have plenty of excess disk to use for intermediate files, if desired.

Comment: No additional disk space for buffering (just the RAM)?

Comment: @Gene You can apply any permutation with O(1) extra space plus N bits (visit all cycles). There's no need to buffer to disk.

Comment: @Gene I didn't think to mention it, but yes I can buffer to disk if desired. I'm not concerned about disk usage in this case, only speed and RAM. I have edited the question to mention this.

Comment: If this is a real world application, why can't you list all permutations and sort them according to a cost function, in which sequential access is favored? You can then follow the sorted list.

Comment: @Maximus I don't want to iterate over all permutations, I have an array that contains one desired permutation. What I'm looking for is an algorithm for the best way to execute that specific permutation.

Comment: You want to read N files from disk, and re-write them according to the desired permutation on the array?

Comment: @Maximus Yes, but I don't have enough memory to store all N records at once. The naive approach would be to random-access the file while writing out the result, but I would instead like to do it in a way that maximizes the sequentiality of the reads.

Comment: @Maximus :-)  The problem can be done in **O(N)** time and **O(1)** space (assuming the permutation list as a given).  You propose a graded *Leland sort* ??  Love it!!

Comment: @Prune :) Well, in this case, you can't make it better than O(N) time. But I was looking for a way to use O(n) space, just because it is a real life application and constants in Big-O sometimes matter. So perhaps we can find a way to use more space and less time ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem.  Find the cycles in your permutation order.  For instance, given five records to permute [1, 0, 3, 4, 2], you have cycles (0, 1) and (2, 3, 4).  You do this by picking an unused starting position; follow the index pointers until you return to your starting point.  The sequence of pointers describes a cycle.

You then permute the records with an internal temporary variable, one record long.

```
temp = disk[0]
disk[0] = disk[1]
disk[1] = temp

temp = disk[2] 
disk[2] = disk[3]
disk[3] = disk[4]
disk[4] = temp
```

Note that you can also perform the permutation as you traverse the pointers.  You will also need some method to recall which positions have already been permuted, such as clearing the permutation index (set it to -1).

Can you see how to generalize that?

Comment: The issue here is sequential access, not just the desire to limit reads/writes. Visiting all the cycles, one at a time, is not going to capitalise on that.

Comment: The issue is to make *one* pass over the permutation, thus rearranging the records for optimal sequential access.

Comment: I think that the permutation could be done faster if it was done in a way that took advantage of sequential reads and writes. Especially because I have some buffer space.

Comment: Consider a situation where the permutation is coherent over blocks of n elements (e.g. with n=4, the permutation 4,5,6,7,0,1,2,3. Your proposal doesn't properly leverage your extra working space to apply the permutation without unnecessary extra disk seeking.

Comment: @Sneftel: right.  The update on the question makes this clear.  This ("my") answer assumes that the permutation is for *future* sequential efficiency, not efficiency of doing the permutation itself.  Needs a full overhaul.

Answer (score 0):

This is an problem with interval coordination.  I'll simplify the notation slightly by changing the memory available to `M` records -- having upper- and lower-case `N` is a little confusing.

First, we re-cast the permutations as a series of intervals, the rotational span during which a record needs to reside in RAM.  If a record needs to be written to a lower-numbered position, we increase the endpoint by the list size, to indicate the wraparound -- have to wait for the next disk rotation.  For instance, using my earlier example, we expand the list:

```
[1, 0, 3, 4, 2]
0 -> 1
1 -> 0+5
2 -> 3
3 -> 4
4 -> 2+5
```

Now, we apply standard greedy scheduling resolution.  First, sort by endpoint:

```
[0, 1]
[2, 3]
[3, 4]
[1, 5]
[4, 7]
```

Now, apply the algorithm for `M-1` "lanes"; the extra one is needed for swap space.    We fill each lane, appending the interval with the earliest endpoint, whose start-point doesn't overlap:

```
[0, 1]   [2, 3]   [3, 4]   [4, 7]
[1, 5]
```

We can do this in a total of 7 "ticks" if M >= 3.  If M=2, we defer the second lane by 2 rotations to [11, 15].

---

`Sneftal`'s nice example gives us more troubles, with deeper overlap:

```
[0, 4]
[1, 5]
[2, 6]
[3, 7]
[4, 0+8]
[5, 1+8]
[6, 2+8]
[7, 3+8]
```

This requires 4 "lanes" if available, deferring lanes as needed if `M` < 5.

---

The pathological case is where every record in the permutation needs to be copied *back* one position, such as [3, 0, 1, 2], with `M`=2.

```
[0, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 5]
[3, 6]
```

In this case, we walk through the deferral cycle multiple times.  At the end of every rotation, we have to defer all remaining intervals by one rotation, resulting in

```
[0, 3]   [3, 6]   [2+4, 5+4]   [1+4+4, 4+4+4]
```

Does that get you moving, or do you need more detail?

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, which might need further improvement. But here it goes:

suppose the hdd has the following structure:

```
5 4 1 2 3
```

And we want to write out this permutation:

```
2 3 5 1 4
```

Since hdd is a circular buffer, and assuming it can only rotate in one direction, we can write the above permutation using shifts as such:

```
5 >> 2
4 >> 3
1 >> 1
2 >> 2
3 >> 2
```

So let's put that in an array, and since we know it is a circular array, lets put its mirrors side by side:

```
| 2 3 1 2 2 | 2 3 1 2 2| 2 3 1 2 2 | 2 3 1 2 2 |... Inf
```

Since we want to favor sequential reads, (or writes) we can put a cost function to the above series. Let the cost function be linear, i. e:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... Inf
```

Now, let us add the cost function to the above series, but how to select the starting point?

The idea is to select the starting point such that you get the maximum congruent monotonically increasing sequence.

For example, if you select the 0 point to be on "3", you'll get

```
(1)    | - 3 2 4 5 | 6 8 7 9 10 | ...
```

If you select the 0 point to be on "2", the one just right of "1", you'll get:

```
(2)    | - - - 2 3 | 4 6 5 7 8 | ...
```

Since we are trying to favor consecutive reads, lets define our read-write function to work as such:

**f()**:

- At any currently pointed hdd location, function will read the currently pointed hdd file, into available RAM. (namely, total space - 1, because we want to save 1 for swap)
- If no available space is left on RAM for read, the function will assert and program will halt.
- At any current hdd location, if ram holds the value that we want to be written in that hdd location, function reads the current file into swap space, writes the wanted value from the ram to hdd, and destroys the value in ram.
- If a value is placed into hdd, function will check if the sequence is completed. If it is, program will return with success.

Now, we should note that if the following holds:

```
shift amount <= n - 1              (n : available memory we can hold)
```

We can traverse the hard disk in once pass using the above function. For example:

```
current: 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3
we want: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
n      : 5
```

We can start anywhere we want, say from the initial "4". We read 4 items sequentially, (n has 4 items now) and we start placing from 0 1 2 3, (we can because n = 5 total, and 4 is used. 1 is used for swap). So the total operations is 4 consecutive reads, and then r-w operations for 8 times.

Using that analogy, it becomes clear that if we subtract "n-1" from equations (1) and (2), the positions which have value "<= 0" will be a better suit for initial position because the ones higher than zero will definitely require another pass.

So we select eq. (2) and subtract, for let's say "n = 3", we subtract 2 from eq. (2):

```
(2)    | - - - 0 1 | 2 4 3 5 6 | ...
```

Now it is clear that, using f(), and starting from 0, assuming n = 3, we will have a starting operation as such: r, r, r-w, r-w, ...

So, how do we do the rest and find minimum cost? We will place an array with initial minimum cost, just below equation (2). The positions in that array will signify where we want f() to be executed.

```
| - - - 0 1 | 2 4 3 5 6 | ...
| - - - 1 1 | 1 1 1 1 1 | ...
```

The second array, the ones with 1's and 0's tell the program where to execute f(). Note that, if we assumed those locations wrong, f() will assert.

Before we start actually placing files into hdd, we of course want to see if the f() positions are correct. We check if there are assertions, we we will try to minimize cost whilst removing all assertions. So, e.g:

```
(1) 1111000000000000001111
(2) 1111111000000000000000
```

(1) obviously has higher cost that (2). So the question simplifies on finding the 1-0 array.

Some ideas on finding the best array:

- Simplest solution is to write out all 1's and turn assertions into 0's. (essentially it's a skip). This method is guaranteed to work.
- Brute force: write an array of as shown in (2) and start shifting 1's to right, in such an order that tries out every permutation available:

  1111111100000000
  1111111010000000
  1111110110000000
  ...
- Full random approach: Plug in mt1997 and start permuting. Whenever you see a sharp drop in cost, stop executing and implement hdd copy-paste. You won't find the global minimum, but you'll get a nice trade-off.
- Genetic algorithms: For permutations where "shift count is much lower than n - 1", the methodology provided in this answer should (?) provide a global minimum and smooth gradients. This allows one to use genetic algorithms without relying on mutations too much.

One advantage I find in this approach is that, since OP mentioned that this is a real life problem, the method provides an easy(ier?) way to change cost functions. It is easier to detect the effect of say, having lots of contigous small files to be copied vs. having a single huge file. Or perhaps rrwwrrww is better than rrrrwwww?

Does any of this even make sense? We will have to try out ...